# How can I customize the thickness and add text to the Volume Slider in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, maui

Trying to recreate this [Volume Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsnQ0.png) in .net MUA.

I've searched through the Microsoft doccumentation but have not been successful in finding the properties I need to make the slider thicker and add text overtop.

I found that setting the thumb image to null will make it invisible but then the top part no longer reaches all the way to the end when the value is maxed.

Comment: Add to question the code you have so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no a such view in the maui, you can custom a control to get the effect you want.